# yahoo_quote_download doesn't return a pandas DataFrame or a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance, stocks

I am using the [yahoo_quote_download library](https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download) to get some data from yahoo finance as either a pandas `DataFrame` or a `csv` file that I can then make into a `DataFrame`. However, when I use `yqd.load_yahoo_quote(ticker, start_date, end_date)`, it returns a list like the following:

```
['Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume',
'2015-01-12,159.000000,159.250000,155.759995,156.440002,135.236679,4182800',
'2015-01-13,157.259995,159.970001,155.679993,156.809998,135.556564,4377500']
```

What I need, though, is a pandas `DataFrame` or a `CSV` file. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mylist = ['Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume',
'2015-01-12,159.000000,159.250000,155.759995,156.440002,135.236679,4182800',
'2015-01-13,157.259995,159.970001,155.679993,156.809998,135.556564,4377500']

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(',') for i in mylist[1:]], columns=list(mylist[0].split(',')))
df
```